# can my Mac act as a bluetooth headset for an Android phone?

Tags: macos, audio, android, bluetooth

I just bought a [Roland VT-4](https://www.roland.com/global/products/vt-4/) (voice transformer). It's a riot.

After installing the drivers on my Mac, the VT-4 is detected as a microphone (and speakers). I can use it with Skype, Zoom, etc.

I'd like to use the VT-4 to make phone calls on my Android phone. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this? Could my Mac act as a Bluetooth headset for my Android phone? Or is there some sort of Bluetooth headset/device that accepts line-in?

Is there a Mac equivalent of [HFP for Linux](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/)?